# Banning an IP address (or subnet) on Debian (still connecting after ufw and iptables)

Tags: debian, fail2ban, ufw

I know the subject of banning IP addresses have been covered multiple times but for some reason I'm failing to address/identify this one.

I am trying to identify a problem with random attacks of some sort on a Debian server. I am already running ufw and fail2ban, but the attacks still happen and I'm a little lost on what to do next.

I am seeing the connections when running `tcptrack -i eth0` and there are hundreds (sometimes thousands) of connections as follows (where of course xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the baddie IP and yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy is the IP address of the server):

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49550     yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:80      SYN_SENT     18s    0 B/s
```

I have run the following:

```
ufw reject from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to any
iptables -I INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP
```

Despite the connections quoting port 80 (they also present for 443) I cannot see them in the `apache2` logs so they do not seem to be making it that far.

Running `htop` it does not seem to be hitting any CPU or RAM issues, it just seems to be overwhelming the server at a lower 'connection' level than that.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: did you think about fail2ban? reject is bad use drop instead because reject tells the emeny it's alive

Comment: @djdomi thanks for your reply. Did you mean drop for ufw? I think it is deny not drop, but no, I did not try that, thanks. fail2ban is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `SYN_SENT` is a normal client TCP socket state that is entered after a client issues a connect to a server socket, till acknowledged by the server yet, after that the client socket state will proceed to `ESTABLISHED`.

Note that the `SYN_SENT` status will not remain for long time. It only lasts for couple of seconds. If not - there can be a problem.

Anyway, this state signaling that this sockets are waiting for the server to connect. As well as this most probably means the clients request never got to the server, because 99% of the time, would indicate some sort of network block due to a firewall (or fail2ban).

Additional drop & reject will change nothing here, especially if net-filter has another rules with higher priority in INPUT chain (e. g. rejecting them from fail2ban).
By the way, see [GH :: fail2ban :: Revisit REJECT vs DROP](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2217) for some thoughts about both).
However `tcpkill`, `killcx`, `ss -K` etc would kill the current state.

Additionally note that if you really have thousands of blocked connections, to speed-up net-filter processing it is advisable to use the sets instead of iptables rules, thus to switch to `iptables-ipset` or `nftables` banning actions of fail2ban.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed reply, mich appreciated. So far my understanding is that I'm seeing all these connections via tcptrack which is showing me ALL the active connections, regardless of whether they are later being dropped or not. My suspicion is that the volume of them (when it happens) is overwhelming something, somewhere and it cannot serve any more connections. The Web server (apache) can then no longer server any connections (I guess no more ports available). I'll take a look at sets as you mention. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is really "no free ports" situation... But you can check the port stats with `ss -s` (and then calculation `65536 - 1000 - total` gives you estimated amount of available ports).
If it is something like a SYN flood, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24171777/7161854 (may be setting of syncookies or reducing a backlog would help).